# Crear función almacenada

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Quiero crear esta función. Intenté desde **Workbench** yendo a Functions/Create function.. y pongo este código:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_calculoHs`(id int)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN

declare cont int;
declare fechainiciovar datetime;
declare fechaterminovar datetime;
    set cont = 0;
    -- select fechainicio into fechainiciovar from servicio where idservicio=id;
    -- select fechatermino into fechaterminovar from servicio where idservicio=id;
    set fechainiciovar=(select fechainicio from servicio where idservicio=id);
    set fechaterminovar=(select fechatermino from servicio where idservicio=id);
    while fechainiciovar < fechaterminovar do
      set fechainiciovar = fechainiciovar + interval 1 hour;
      set cont=cont+1;
    end while;
RETURN cont;

end
```

pero me da este error:
ERROR 1418: This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Probé poniéndole el `not deterministic` después del `RETURNS INTEGER`, que creo que se declara ahí, y tampoco funciona. También probé reemplazando los `set` con lo que está comentado `--`.
Los nombres de los campos están bien, es una tabla `servicio` que tiene `idServicio`, `fechaInicio` y `ferchaTermino` ambos `datetime`. La idea es ir sumándole una hora a `fechaInicio` hasta que llegue a `ferchaTermino` entonces el `cont` me va a retornar la cantidad de horas que hay entre `fechaInicio` y `ferchaTermino`, ya sé que esto se puede hacer de una forma sencilla, pero la idea es aprender a usar variables y además porque después le quiero a agregar `if fechaInicio between 8:00:00 and 17:59:59 then set cont=cont+1;`, o sea que  con esto último busco que me cuente solo las horas que están en ese rango, las horas hábiles digamos

Comment: bueno, ya lo solucioné ejecutando esto `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;`